# Unable to launch web via Azure Dev Spaces

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-dev-spaces

I got the error below following the steps [Develop with .NET Core on Kubernetes with Azure Dev Spaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/quickstart-netcore-visualstudio?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).

[image]

> Starting warmup for project 'Webfrontend'. Using dev space 'default'
>   with target 'myapp-hello' Release "azds-1d5814-default-webfrontend"
>   does not exist. Installing it now. NAME:
>   azds-1d5814-default-webfrontend LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Jun 26 15:52:57
>   2019 NAMESPACE: default STATUS: DEPLOYED RESOURCES: NAME         TYPE 
>   CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)  AGE
>   ==> v1/Service webfrontend  ClusterIP  10.0.156.89         80/TCP   1s
>   ==> v1beta1/Ingress NAME         HOSTS                                       ADDRESS         PORTS  AGE webfrontend 
>   default.webfrontend.wqlm7l5jbj.cus.azds.io  52.173.150.205  80     1s
>   NOTES: NAME         READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
>   ==> v1beta2/Deployment webfrontend  0/1    0           0          1s   http://default.webfrontend.wqlm7l5jbj.cus.azds.io/
>   1. Get the application URL by running these commands: Building container image... Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.927MB
>   Step 1/13 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
>   ---> 155911c343f3 Step 2/13 : ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 0a860927aa11 Step 3/13 : ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 9aff467dfcc3 Step 4/13 : ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 4eec944c4cdb Step 5/13 : EXPOSE 80
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 051a7179cc8d Step 6/13 : WORKDIR /src
>   ---> c265c50b4cb2
>   ---> Using cache Step 7/13 : COPY ["Webfrontend/Webfrontend.csproj", "Webfrontend/"]
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 29e207ff4a3d Step 8/13 : RUN dotnet restore "Webfrontend/Webfrontend.csproj"
>   ---> 114d8778f570 Step 9/13 : COPY . .
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 45bccf0ad047 Step 10/13 : WORKDIR "/src/Webfrontend"
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 7ef376f04ab7 Step 13/13 : ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> acf4addbf8a8 Successfully built acf4addbf8a8
>   ---> e173184b7977 Successfully tagged webfrontend:devspaces-x016b947d6bdae4f7
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 0b2cafae008c Step 11/13 : RUN dotnet build --no-restore "Webfrontend.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION Step 12/13 : RUN echo
>   "exec dotnet run --no-build --no-launch-profile -c
>   $BUILD_CONFIGURATION --" > /entrypoint.sh Built container image in 1s
>   Waiting for container... 5s
>
> Service 'webfrontend' port 'http' is available at
>   http://default.webfrontend.wqlm7l5jbj.cus.azds.io/ Service
>   'webfrontend' port 80 (http) is available via port forwarding at
>   http://localhost:28228 An error occurred during warmup for project
>   'Webfrontend': System.InvalidOperationException: Container cannot be
>   reached.    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.DevSpaces.Client.Connection.ContainerConnector.d__34.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.DevSpaces.Client.Connection.ContainerConnector.d__26.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.DevSpaces.Client.ManagementClients.ServiceManagementClientImplementation.d__96.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.DevSpaces.Client.ManagementClients.ServiceManagementClientImplementation.d__92.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.DevSpaces.Client.ManagementClients.ServiceManagementClient.d__26.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Client.DevSpacesServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Client.DevSpacesServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.<ExecuteOperationAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Package.Services.DebugService.d__25.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Package.Services.BackgroundWarmupService.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Package.Services.BackgroundWarmupService.d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Package.Services.BackgroundWarmupService.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<b__4>d.MoveNext()
>   Enabling debugging... Using dev space 'default' with target
>   'myapp-hello' Release "azds-1d5814-default-webfrontend" does not
>   exist. Installing it now. NAME:   azds-1d5814-default-webfrontend LAST
>   DEPLOYED: Wed Jun 26 15:53:29 2019 NAMESPACE: default STATUS: DEPLOYED
>   RESOURCES:
>   ==> v1/Service NAME         TYPE       CLUSTER-IP  EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)  AGE webfrontend  ClusterIP  10.0.145.8         80/TCP
>   0s
>   ==> v1beta1/Ingress NAME         HOSTS                                       ADDRESS         PORTS  AGE webfrontend 
>   default.webfrontend.wqlm7l5jbj.cus.azds.io  52.173.150.205  80     0s
>   ==> v1beta2/Deployment NAME         READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE webfrontend  0/1    0           0          0s NOTES:
>   1. Get the application URL by running these commands:   http://default.webfrontend.wqlm7l5jbj.cus.azds.io/ Building container
>   image... Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.927MB Step 1/13 :
>   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
>   ---> 155911c343f3 Step 2/13 : ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 0a860927aa11 Step 3/13 : ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 9aff467dfcc3 Step 4/13 : ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 4eec944c4cdb Step 5/13 : EXPOSE 80
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 051a7179cc8d Step 6/13 : WORKDIR /src
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> c265c50b4cb2 Step 7/13 : COPY ["Webfrontend/Webfrontend.csproj", "Webfrontend/"]
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 29e207ff4a3d Step 8/13 : RUN dotnet restore "Webfrontend/Webfrontend.csproj"
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 114d8778f570 Step 9/13 : COPY . .
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 45bccf0ad047 Step 10/13 : WORKDIR "/src/Webfrontend"
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 0b2cafae008c Step 11/13 : RUN dotnet build --no-restore "Webfrontend.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> e173184b7977 Step 12/13 : RUN echo "exec dotnet run --no-build --no-launch-profile -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION --" > /entrypoint.sh
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> 7ef376f04ab7 Step 13/13 : ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> acf4addbf8a8 Successfully built acf4addbf8a8 Successfully tagged webfrontend:devspaces-x016b947dea959b9c Built container image in <1s
>   Waiting for container... 4s
>
> Service 'webfrontend' port 'http' is available at
>   http://default.webfrontend.wqlm7l5jbj.cus.azds.io/ Service
>   'webfrontend' port 80 (http) is available via port forwarding at
>   http://localhost:28228

**Update**

The popup box displays at the end of the text above.

Below will be displayed if succeed:

> Service 'webfrontend' port 'http' is available at http://webfrontend.1234567890abcdef1234.eus.azds.io/
>
> Service 'webfrontend' port 80 (http) is available at http://localhost:62266
>
> Completed warmup for project 'webfrontend' in 125 seconds.

VS 2017, 19

Win 7

Comment: After which step in the document are you seeing this error?

Comment: Please see my update